# (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I got thid error:

```
(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

I have read that I can increase database timeout.
What do I do?
**Settings.py:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'c9',
        'USER': ddd,
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': ddd,
        'PORT': '3306',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True
    },
     'OPTIONS': {
        'timeout': 99999999,
        'net_read_timeout': 9999999
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Database object declaration is not correct, OPTIONS should be declared inside default object

```
#settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'c9',
        'USER': ddd,
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': ddd,
        'PORT': '3306',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'OPTIONS':{
            'timeout': 99999999,
            'net_read_timeout': 9999999
        },
    }
}
```